# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

Friends

I have got an error which tells "Index was outside the bounds of the array"  I dont know y it was happening since after completeting the for loop  and entering the loop fresh again it was showing the variable value when exited from the loop before.

```
        int[,] arrScr = new int[lstTest.Count, cnt2 + 3];
        string[,] arrName = new string[lstTest.Count, cnt2 + 3];
        int p;

        for (i = 0; i < lstTest.Count; i++)
        {
            using (DataTableReader dtr3 = ds.Tables["scord_mark_table" + (i + 1).ToString()].CreateDataReader())
            {
                p = 0;
                while (dtr3.Read())
                {
                    arrName[i, 2 + p] = dtr3[15].ToString();
                    for (int k = 2; k < 12; k++)
                    {
                        arrScr[i, 2 + p] += Convert.ToInt32(dtr3[k].ToString());
                    }
                    p++;
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: It seems very odd that you should have an exception showing on that statement anyway. Can you please show us your complete code (as text rather than as an image)?

Comment: I'm sure the part hidden by the exception message has something to do with it :P

Comment: Its just plain count-index mismatch. ensure you have enough items inside the array. Do some conditional logic before you access array

Comment: Green , sorry to ask you does arrName matter to the problem.

Comment: nope I was thinking that arrName is behind that exception before you post the code :)

Comment: John, sorry it was because dtr3[12] was returning null. But I dont know why the error flag was set on for loop instead of the the actual problem  statement above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is in `dtr3[12]`?  does it return `null`?
What is the value of `cnt2`?

Answer (score 2):

Change `k <= 12` to  `k < 12`.

If this is not the cause of your problem you should rewrite `k <= 12` to  `k < 13` as that is the convention most coders are used to read and write.

Comment: But thats not whats causing this error. Its just that somewhere index to some array doesn't match with the actual count. Even if k = 13 wont enter inside for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your array does not contain as many elements as you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to exit from the loop as k = 13 because the last valid value of k is 12, then it went through the loop, executed k++ (making it 13). At which point it fails the condition because 13 > 12 and that's when it actually exits.

Comment: But thats not whats causing this error. Its just that somewhere index to some array doesn't match with the actual count